# Как сделать что бы объект правильно отталкивался от другого объекта | Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Есть шарик и стены. Шарику присваивается сила с помощью velocity. Как после коллизии задать шарику направление так, что бы он как-бы отбился и было похоже на реальность. На рисунке стрелками обозначена примерная траектория.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вектор направления шарика **V**, а единичная нормаль к стенке **N**, то после удара скорость будет

```
d = V.dot.N  (скалярное произведение)
newV = V - 2 * d * N
```

Comment: Что значит dot? Немного не понял

Comment: Про скалярное произведение не почитали?  `d=V.x*N.x + V.y*N.y`

Comment: Почитал, просто немного не понял. Спасибо